# Абсолютнный путь для import в Node.js ES6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, импорт

Есть ли возможность использовать абсолютный путь в import в es6 модулях Node.js?
В случае require допускается require.main.require('./absolute/path/file'). Нужно что-то похожее

Comment: абсолютный путь с точки не начинается

Comment: Тут дело в том, что мы исходим относительно запущенного модуля, т.е require.main

Answer (score 3):

Нормального варианта не нашел, но есть замечательный костыль в виде: [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)

ДО установки модуля путь выглядел так:

```
require('../../../../some/very/deep/module')
```

После:

```
module = require('@deep/module')
```

---

Чтобы создать псевдоним для каталога необходимо в `package.json` вписать объект:

```
"_moduleAliases": {
    "@root"      : ".",
    "@deep"      : "src/some/very/deep/directory/or/file",
    "@my_module" : "lib/some-file.js",
    "something"  : "src/foo"
}
```

Где `ключ` - название псевдонима

А `значение` - путь к каталогу.

---

Подробнее можно посмотреть в документации самого модуля

### [`module-alias`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)

Answer (score 0):

[process.cwd()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) или [__filename](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename)

```js
const root = process.cwd();
const customModule = require(`${root}/lib/customModule`);
```

или:

```js
console.log(__filename);
```